# Как создать пользовательские функции?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, помогите новичку "Как создать пользовательские функции ?" в php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.php.su/functions/custom/

и ваапче это очень хороший ресурс :)

Comment: Спасибо вам :)

Comment: А иначе зачем мы тут все? :)

Comment: и кстати - благодарности тут принимаются голосованием ЗА :))))